# Any good programming practices/tools to reduce memory fragmentation in JS?

Tags: javascript, firefox, memory-management, memory-leaks

I was noticing very high usage of memory in Firefox, and I saw pages like Gmail and another heavy web-app I was working on, were >100mb! Looking through and seeing some high "unused-gc-things" in about:memory, I found this bug has been reported [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=989379) and [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=276342) and is a common problem without a good solution :(

Is there a good tool for detecting arenas of un-garbage-collectable objects short of compiling a special build of Firefox or other browser? And are there better methodologies of writing web-apps that don't use much memory? I would imagine using ArrayBuffer or asm.js may be more efficient as it has one set memory pool, but that doesn't play well with the usual DOM-based interaction and javascript function-al "class"-based programming of most web-apps.